# Как правильно подключать QThreads к SQLite?

Tags: python, многопоточность, sqlite, sqlite3, qthread

Ожидается штук 20 потоков, всем надо как то сообщаться с `SQLite .db` базой на чтение и запись.

Никак не могу сообразить как это правильно оформить. Желательно, чтобы команды со всех потоков выполнялись последовательно (чтобы не заполучить конфликт когда два потока вдруг попробуют одновременно ломануться в одну запись).

Подключение?:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('d:\\my.db') as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        pass
```

И поточность:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from time import sleep

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread

class Work(QThread):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for x in range(100):
            print(self.var, x)
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    threads = []
    for t in range(3):
        threads.append(Work(t))
        threads[t].start()
        sleep(0.1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: При записи SQLite накладывает блокировку на файл. Какой-то поток захватит её, остальные получат отлуп. Ничего страшного не случится. Просто делаете повтор операции.

Comment: Как вариант, не создавать в каждом потоке новое соединение, а использовать одно и то же соединение во всех потоках. Это автоматически сериализует доступ через него.

Comment: По крайней, обратите внимание на прагму [journal_mode](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode). Вероятно, есть смысл установить WAL. Там по ссылкам много информации. Не зная ваших подробностей, не могу сказать, что лучше.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ага, спасибо. Там запросов немного и они довольно простые ожидаются. Типа `select column from table where done = 0 limit 1` и соответственный ему апдейт в `done = 1`, просто обработка не за доли секунды, и хочется распределить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А передавать именно коннект, а потом каждому свой курсор, или передавать и коннект и курсор? `with sqlite3.connect('d:\\my.db') as connection: for t in range(3): threads.append(Work(connection))`?

Comment: Передавать коннект.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Ответом оформишь? Я бы галочку поставил.